Example of map and a vector field such that the vector field is not projectable?
Def: given a smooth map $ \pi : M \to N $ between manifolds, a vector field $ X \in \mathfrak{X}(M) $ is said to be $ \pi $-projectable to a vector field $ V \in \mathfrak{X}(N) $ if
$$
(d\pi)_x(X_x) = V_{\pi(x)} \quad \forall x \in M.
$$
What would be an example of $ \pi $ and a vector field that IS NOT $ \pi $-projectable ?
I tried the following but it looks like this does not work since the zero vector field is allowed in the definition
Consider $ \pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} :\pi(x, y) = x.$
Then $d\pi(x, y)(v_1, v_2) = v_1.$
Now, consider the vector field $ X = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $ on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, so that
$$
d\pi(x, y)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = 0.
$$
For $ X $ to be $ \pi $-projectable, there should exist a vector field $ V $ on $ \mathbb{R} $ such that:
$$
d\pi(x, y)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right) = V_{\pi(x, y)}.
$$
The only possible candidate for $ V $ would be the zero vector field, but  then this makes $ X = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} $ $ \pi $-projectable.

A vector field $X$ would not be $\pi$-projectable if it does not agree on fibers. For instance, consider the same map $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ and let the vector field $X$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ be $X = y\frac{d}{dx}$. If we assume $V$ is the $\pi$-projection of $X$, then we must have $V_x = (d\pi)_{(x, y)}(X_{(x, y)}) = y\frac{d}{dx}$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$. However, this is absurd since $y$ is independent of $x$ and can be chosen arbitrarily

So what V are you taking ?   because one should fix a V to check the definition

Well, I'm claiming that no such V exists.

In my example, would it work if I fixed $V=\partial_x$ ? Since $d\pi_p(X_p)=0$ then it is not $\pi$-projectable to such $V$, but it would be$ \pi$-projectable to $0$, of I had fixed $V=0$

Well, it makes more sense to say that some $X$ is $\pi$-projectable when there exists some $V$ for which you have the obvious compatibility property.

I agree, so that is what you're using then? I was given the definition as I wrote it, but it does not make much sense, do you have a reference with that definition so that I can check what is the correct definition?

Lee might use the terminology "$F$-related vector fields"

Can you explain a bit further how no V exists in your example?

Compute $(d\pi){(x,2)}(X{(x,2)})$ and $(d\pi){(x,3)}(X{(x,3)})$.
